# Pass a select tag value to a route url on laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

How do I do this in laravel while passing it to a route

```
<select id="selectUser" name="selectUser" class="form-control text-md-right" onchange="alert(Getfield());">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select Service</option>
  @foreach($ListServices as $lst)
     <option value="{{$lst->ServiceName}}">{{ $lst->ServiceName }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>

<?php

if(isset(!empty($_GET['selectUser'])) { 
       Route + $_GET['selectUser']
}
?>
```

This is without a form method just using link route while passing the value of select tag?

Comment: Explain your error?

Comment: how about sending a request to your controller and running a function there?

Comment: return redirect("/you-url")->withInput(); For more information please follow this link  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/dynamic-route-path-in-form-action-based-on-the-selected-option?page=1

Comment: There is no error but i'm exploring on laravel and like how do like a post back echo it's like in native php when we do a form action="" it regularly post back same url link but if the input field is filled and you do a echo $_POST['fieldname']; it regularly post back it's value how do you do that in laravel framework?

Comment: you send back the form data to a controller in laravel, use $request to fetch all input values.

Comment: thats my question cause i have underform in same page which if i refresh it would be gone so that is why i need not to refresh the page but able to retrieve and display a data without loosing the others due to page refresh

Answer (score -1):

why not pass it as query string

```
{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(),array('somevariable' => 'value'))
```

If you want to redirect back to self with option select value use javascript class and jquery do something like

```
('#selectuser').change(function (e) {
    $.redirect('{{ route(Route::currentRouteName()}}',
    {
        user: e.val(),
    });
});
```

and then use `$request->get('user')` to access.

Comment: how do you call it in blade view? like attach it on button or maybe href link or possible even just input field

Comment: we do it in blade like <a href="{{route('route_name','optional query string')}}" > link </a>

Comment: you can add query string in route?? really? sorry i really am just exploring laravel i'm from csharp